# Digital signage: flash or html5?

Tags: html, flash

I'm currently tasked with making some digital signage, which will display an agenda of sorts for an event in a table format, along with some header and footer graphics. I'm trying to make my decision to use either html5 or flash, however I don't have much experience with digital signage, so I was hoping for some input. My main concern is how html5 will rescale vs flash on different screen sizes. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I recomend that you use HTML5, even though to me, flash seems more powerfull, HTML5 is very practical and very easy to rescale, i think your decision depends of your experience with these diferent digital signages.

I use flash, but only because i can't choose!

Answer (score 0):

I also work for a digital signage company and have built many projects in both Flash and HTML5 and I would always go with HTML5.  Support for Flash isn't as strong as it once was and you can do everything in HTML5 that you could have done in Flash.  Rescaling in HTML isn't much a concern if you use modern HTML development and code the pages using Responsive Web Design.